# Show that $f_k(x)=\sin(x/k)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[-R,R]$for all $R>0, k\geqslant 1$

Tags: real-analysis

> For $k\geqslant 1$ we have the function $f_k(x)=\sin(x/k)$. I want to
>   show that it converges uniformly to $0$ on $[-R,R]$ for all $R>0.$

I know I need to prove that \begin{equation}\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall x\in[-R,R]\quad\forall k\geqslant N:\qquad \left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)\right|\leqslant\epsilon.\end{equation}

I can choose an $N$, which will let me change $k$ in my function. But then there is still the $x$ in the function, so that the values will still be between $0$ and $1$. Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any real number $t$,
$$|\sin(t)|\leq |t|,$$
which implies that
$$\max_{x\in[-R,R]}\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)\right|\leq \max_{x\in[-R,R]}\left|\frac{x}{k}\right|.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: We can take $N$ larger then $R$, so that $\left|\frac{x}{k}\right|$ goes to $0$ for $k\geqslant N$. Is it okay like this?

Comment: Given $R>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ what is a "good" $N$?

Comment: $N\geqslant\frac{\epsilon}{R}$. Then $\left|\frac{x}{k}\right|\leqslant\left|\frac{R}{k}\right|\leqslant\left|\frac{R}{N}\right|\leqslant\epsilon$

Comment: From your last inequality $N\geq R/\epsilon$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{N}\leqslant\frac{R}{\epsilon}$, so $\frac{R}{N}\leqslant\frac{R}{\frac{R}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$, right?

Comment: No. $N\geqslant\frac{R}{\epsilon}$, so $\frac{R}{N}\leqslant\frac{R}{\frac{R}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$